# Unable to map host folder to container folder with docker -v

Tags: docker-volume

I'm trying to containerize a react app. While looking for a solution to link the files from my computer to the container I came across this tutorial: https://www.ionos.com/community/server-cloud-infrastructure/docker/understanding-and-managing-docker-container-volumes/

Dockerfile:

> WORKDIR /app

Docker command:

> docker run --name react -it --rm -p 3000:3000 -v $(pwd)/src:/src {image} sh

when I edit my app.js file from my computer I expected change to be reflected in my container. but that hasn't happened. Can someone explain where I went wrong and if so a possible way to link container folder to host folder?

Answer (score 0):

Okay after some digging around I found the answer. Apparently the default machine that runs on vm that comes bundled with docker-toolbox only has access to the files in c:/users directory. So you have to go to settings, then shared folders and add a new folder giving it access to the directory that you have your projects on.